# Jquery Mobile navigation page refresh css removed

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have  two pages from which i am planning to navigate using JQM mobile framework, I am planning for multiple pages, for my code to be tidy i decided to have the multiple pages in different html files. On navigating to next screen page refresh the page CSS is not loading.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).swipeleft(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("page2.html");
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 1</h3>
                    <p><a href="page2.html" data-transition="slide" >I'm the collapsible content for section 1</a></p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 2</h3>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 3</h3>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div data-role="footer"></div> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 : I have the below code

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dom-cache="true">
<div data-role="header"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Page 2</h3>
                <p>
                    <a href="page3.html" data-transition="slide">I'm the
                        collapsible content for section 1</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
                <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The navigation happens but when i refresh the page the css are removed.How to have multiple page and navigate between screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was referring to http://m.stanford.edu/#events which used older version JQM

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1 jquery.mobile1.0a4.1.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
```

and in latest version ie

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

The above issue is done for the latest version by

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your **page1.html** to below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 1</h3>
                    <p><a href="page2.html" data-transition="slide" >I'm the collapsible content for section 1</a></p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 2</h3>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h3>Section 3</h3>
                    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div data-role="footer"></div> 
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#page1').on('pageshow',function(event){
    $("#page1").swiperight(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("page2.html");
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and change your **page2.html** as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Page 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dom-cache="true">
        <div data-role="header"></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Page 2</h3>
                        <p>
                            <a href="page3.html" data-transition="slide">I'm the
                                collapsible content for section 1</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Section 2</h3>
                        <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h3>Section 3</h3>
                        <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer"></div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#page2').on('pageshow',function(event){
    alert('page2 loaded');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work now. Please tell me what happens. I wrapped the script inside `$('#page2').on('pageshow',function(event){});`. That's the only change I've done.

Comment: Please explain to OP why you offered this change.

Comment: It immediately navigates to next page page2. It don't solve my problem

Comment: check the updated code. I've assinged the swipe event to the page's ID.

Comment: http://m.stanford.edu/#events/today/ check this jqm page they are having only standard JQM format page but it works fine. even in refresh

Comment: Did you try the new code?? does it worked?? yeah JQM style should not be removed even when refreshed.!

Comment: just adding the swipe event to the page it working fine. i want to make it work like the JQM navigation as working in stanford university.

Comment: I hope the question is about css styles getting removed. Not about cloning stanford university. You should ask a new qustion. BTW you need to build ListView to clone stanford university's page.

Comment: by importing the css and jqm in second page it works, but by the example of stanford they are not importing JQM css but works fine, how are they doing it.

Comment: Check the multipage template structure here. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25946/discussion-between-ranjith-and-mayu-mayooresan)

Comment: Mayu Thanks for your finally found it the site was using older version JQM thanks for your time.